# How can I return null of denominator is 0 in this method Java

Tags: java

I am struggling with creation of a to calculate fractions and return in an array[3]. So if nominator is 7 and denominator is 3 it should return {2,1,3}, a fraction part and a integer part. If denominator is 0, the integer division should not be executed and I have to return null (not print it). That is what I am struggling with. My code is below:

```
public class Main{

public static int[] fraction(int nominator, int denominator){

    int quota=0; 
    int numerator=0;
      
    try{

         quota = nominator / denominator; 
         numerator = nominator % denominator;         

       }
      
       catch(java.lang.ArithmeticException e)
    {

       if(denominator==0)
       {  
         quota =0;
         numerator=0;  

           
         
       }
     
    }
    
    int [] integerArray ={quota, numerator,denominator};
    
    return integerArray; 
    
  } 

}
```

Comment: Simply add `if (denominator == 0) { return null; }` at the beginning.

Comment: it wont compile that's what i tried .. how can that be?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ah u said in the top. It wouldn't work inside the try catch. I deleted try catch and just told if (denominator ==0){ return null;} else execute the rest. it works :)

Comment: Don't "fix" the code in your question.  It makes the answers look a bit silly.   They look like they are suggesting a fix that is unnecessary because the code already contains the fix.

Comment: If you need to ask a followup question that depends on the fix ... ask it as a new question.

Comment: Remember ... the **real** purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a library of Question and Answers that will be helpful to future readers.  For that to work, the questions need to be clear and focused, and the answers need to relate to the question ... as it appears to the future reader.  Your getting help on your homework is incidental.

Comment: also consider throwing a checked Exception instead of returning null - you get a compiler error if not handling checked Exceptions; not checking for `null` will (eventually) give a runtime Exception

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for commenting. I will remember that for another time. I got my answers which leads me in the correct direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can just return early once you checked the denominator is 0.

```
public static int[] fraction(int nominator, int denominator){

    if (denominator == 0){
        return null
    }
    int quota = nominator / denominator; 
    int numerator = nominator % denominator;      
    
    int [] integerArray = {quota, numerator,denominator};
    
    return integerArray;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can proceed in 2 different ways:

1. you can control if denominator is 0 before the try and return null instantly (as said in the comments)
2. you used try catch so you can return null into the catch block without further controls because you catch an exception

there should not be any compilation errors so if you get one try to read the console and find what's the problem.